# How to resize NSTableView cell so that text view inside does not loose focus

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have `NSTableView` with custom `NSTableViewRow`. When user types in text i would like the row to resize while user is typing.
Now if i call on tableView `reloadData` cell looses the focus.

Is there any other way to make `NSTableView` resize the heights ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reloading all the data you can use

```
reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:
```

this reloads the particular row/column you specify (in your case the one that was just edited), and preserves the tableview selection.

Comment: I've tried it, it causes the height to change but unfortunately text view looses focus so not valid solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the problem:

I haven't found any way of reloading row height in `NSTableView` without loosing focus. So My solution was to get rid of `NSTableView` and use `NSScrollView` with some customized `NSViews` instead.

Update: I recently noticed method which can be used to resize cell, dont know if it makes the text view not loose the focus, but thought it might help:

```
[self.tableView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row]];
```